# ECDiffieHellmanCng Implementation And Mechanism

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I've been reading on different cryptography algorithms and I came across the "Diffie Hellman Cryptography Next Generation". I've made a lot of searches about this algorithm and I have  found that it is an Asymmetric cryptography system which is in some ways rivaling RSA. I had a look at the .Net's `System.Security.Cryptography` and I found it provides Diffie-Hellman cryptography as well. So I wen't to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng%28v=vs.100%29) and there I found a very nice example on how to use it in C#, but this example has brought some questions into my mind. Let me copy some part of the code first: (I don't post the full code as my question is mainly about this part)

```
public static byte[] alicePublicKey;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (ECDiffieHellmanCng alice = new ECDiffieHellmanCng())
    {

        alice.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
        alice.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
        alicePublicKey = alice.PublicKey.ToByteArray();
        Bob bob = new Bob();
        CngKey k = CngKey.Import(bob.bobPublicKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
        byte[] aliceKey = alice.DeriveKeyMaterial(CngKey.Import(bob.bobPublicKey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob));
        byte[] encryptedMessage = null;
        byte[] iv = null;
        Send(aliceKey, "Secret message", out encryptedMessage, out iv);
        bob.Receive(encryptedMessage, iv);
    }

}

private static void Send(byte[] key, string secretMessage, out byte[] encryptedMessage, out byte[] iv)
{
    using (Aes aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        aes.Key = key;
        iv = aes.IV;

        // Encrypt the message
        using (MemoryStream ciphertext = new MemoryStream())
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ciphertext, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            byte[] plaintextMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretMessage);
            cs.Write(plaintextMessage, 0, plaintextMessage.Length);
            cs.Close();
            encryptedMessage = ciphertext.ToArray();
        }
    }
}

}
```

When I look at this, I see that it is the AES that is doing everything, and the `ECDiffieHellman` is only responsible for providing a key for the AES algorithm. In the meanwhile it itself is based on the SHA256 hashing system.

So my question is, what exactly is this "ECDiffieHellmanCng" doing in this case? What I see is a hybrid cryptography system, one for key exchange and the other for the encryption, this has conflict with what I've read over the internet about this Diffie Hellman algorithm, most sources list it under Asymmetric encryption systems but this example is not showing the same thing. I say this because when I look the `AliceKey` I see that, it is made based on a Public Key that has been probably made using SHA256 and it itself is not encrypting/ decryption anything.

Comment: Diffie–Hellman is a key exchange algorithm. It was published in 1976 (cf. RSA in 1977), so I'm not sure how "Next Generation" is applicable here. However, your code seems to be using Elliptic Curve Diffie–Hellman, which is another, somewhat related algorithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have stumbled upon is actually the "cryptographic development platform" called "[Cryptography Next Generation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730763%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)" developed by Microsoft. From a cryptographic point of view there is nothing revolutionary or "next gen" in there, just a new library implementing or wrapping known cryptographic algorithms.

[Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) is one of the oldest and  most respected [asymmetric cryptographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) algorithms available to us. It allows two parties to exchange a private key in such a way that a passive eavesdropper of their communication cannot deduce the exchanged key. As such Diffie-Hellman is an important building block for many cryptographic protocols. It's not an encryption algorithm though. After the private key has been deduced by the two parties they still have to use a symmetric algorithm to encrypt their following communication.

This is not unique to Diffie-Hellman though, every asymmetric algorithm is used with many symmetric algorithms to build a working and secure protocol. RSA for example only allows you to use encrypt 256 bytes at a time with a 2048bit key. And for security purposes you should never user raw RSA to encrypt data. I've described one combination to use RSA securely to encrypt arbitrary data in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22949669/371137).

*Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman* is a variant of the classic Diffie-Hellman that uses an other mathematical structure - an [elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve) - as a foundation together with the same fundamental idea behind Diffie-Hellman. It has gained some attention lately as it considerable faster than the classic variant while achieving the same security level.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I have a question, what you mentioned " It allows two parties to exchange a private key in such a way that a passive eavesdropper of their communication cannot deduce the exchanged key." is true according to MSDN. But if this key is supposed to be exchanged over an unsecured network, the eavesdropper can easily catch the exchanged key, is that right? if it this not true, how exactly does ECDH provide that advantage ?

Comment: @CMonster Diffie-Hellman uses a so called trapdoor function. For a big prime `p`, a base `1<g<p-1` and a random value `0<a<p-1` it is easy to compute `g^a mod p` out of `p`,`g` and `a` but difficult to compute `a` out of `p`, `g` and `g^a mod p`. This is called the discrete logarithm problem. Thus you can publish `g^a mod p` without fear that someone computes `a`. You can read more about the inner workings on the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange